# select(2) on FIFO on macOS

Tags: c, system-calls, portability

On Linux the included program returns from `select` and exits:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra select_test.c -o select_test
$ ./select_test
reading from read end
closing write end
first read returned 0
second read returned 0
selecting with read fd in fdset
select returned
```

On OS X, the `select` blocks forever and the program does not exit.  The Linux behavior matches my expectation and appears to conform to the following bit of the POSIX manual page for select:

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.)

Since read(2) on the read end of the fifo will always return `EOF`, my reading says that it should always be considered ready by select.

Is macOS's behavior here well-known or expected?  Is there something else in this example that leads to the behavior difference?

A further note is that if I remove the `read` calls then macOS's `select` returns. This and some other experiments seem to indicate that once an EOF has been read from the file, it will no longer be marked as ready if `select` is called on it later.

### Example Program

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILENAME "select_test_tmp.fifo"

int main() 
{
    pid_t pid;
    int r_fd, w_fd;
    unsigned char buffer[10];
    fd_set readfds;

    mkfifo(FILENAME, S_IRWXU);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) 
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) 
    {
        w_fd = open(FILENAME, O_WRONLY);

        if (w_fd == -1) 
        {
            perror("open");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("closing write end\n");
        close(w_fd);
        exit(0);
    }

    r_fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (r_fd == -1) 
    {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("reading from read end\n");

    if (read(r_fd, &buffer, 10) == 0) 
    {
        printf("first read returned 0\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("first read returned non-zero\n");
    }

    if (read(r_fd, &buffer, 10) == 0) 
    {
        printf("second read returned 0\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("second read returned non-zero\n");
    }

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(r_fd, &readfds);

    printf("selecting with read fd in fdset\n");
    if (select(r_fd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) 
    {
        perror("select");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("select returned\n");
    unlink(FILENAME);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Macintosh, the pipes are treated in the same way as sockets, via the `read` function.  This behaviour is induced because you are trying to `read` the `select_test_tmp.fifo` file, and it blocks whenever you have empty input.  The EOF is by default written to the pipe after each write operation.

One way to verify this is, to run `cat select_test_tmp.fifo` from your command line.  It will wait until it gets some input, before returning-- unless you terminate it first.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You confuse "write" with "write and close write end". You cannot "send" an EOF and a write operation does not put the read end of the socket/pipe into EOF until the write end is closed. Example: if you fire the command `cat <(echo Robert) <(tail -f /dev/null) | cat`, a write operation completes and succeeds, yet the pipe still blocks on `read`.

Answer (score 0):

Your hypotheses are not correct.

The expected behavior is that once all the writers have closed the write end of the fifo that they hold, the read end provides a one time call on `read` that returns 0 bytes. You are not supposed to call additional `read` afterwards : the read end should be closed and open again to do so, or re-created if it is a pipe.

If you stick to this rule, you will get consistent behavior across platforms.

Here is an example program inspired by yours that behaves correctly on both platforms:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FILENAME "select_test_tmp.fifo"

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int r_fd, w_fd;
    unsigned char buffer[8192];
    fd_set master_set, working_set;
    char const * message = "Hello there\n";
    mkfifo(FILENAME, S_IRWXU);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) exit(1);

    if (pid == 0) {
        w_fd = open(FILENAME, O_WRONLY);
        if (w_fd == -1) exit(1);
        write(w_fd, message, strlen(message));
        close(w_fd);
        exit(0);
    }

    r_fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (r_fd < 0) exit(1);

    FD_ZERO(&master_set);
    FD_SET(r_fd, &master_set);
    int finished = 0;
    while (!finished) {
      memcpy(&working_set, &master_set, sizeof(master_set));
      int rc = select(r_fd + 1, &working_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      if (rc < 1) exit(1); // No timeout so rc == 0 is also an error here
      for (int fd = 0; fd < r_fd +1; ++fd) {
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &working_set)) {
          if (fd == r_fd) { // Our fifo
            // Read data and print it in stdout
            ssize_t nb_bytes = read(r_fd, buffer, 8192);
            if (nb_bytes < 0) {
              exit(1);
            }
            else if (0 == nb_bytes) {
              finished = 1;
            }
            else {
              write(1,buffer,nb_bytes);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    unlink(FILENAME);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: "You are not supposed to call additional read afterwards": Do you know a good source for this rule?

Comment: @StevenD no need to look far. `man 2 read` says "Upon reading end-of-file, zero is returned.". Then you go to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file), which first sentence about EOF says: "In computing, end-of-file (commonly abbreviated EOF) is a condition in a computer operating system where no more data can be read from a data source."